# Using positional arguments from argparse as function name

Tags: python, argparse

I have set up a script with argparse that gives me the following NameSpace:

```
Namespace(action='list', input='all', target='domain')
```

I have made a few functions which are called according to the positionals, and at the moment I have a working situation by calling them with blurbs of code like this one:

```
if args.action == 'list':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)
elif args.target == 'domain':
    domain_list()
elif args.target == 'forwarding':
    forwarding_list()
elif args.target == 'transport':
    transport_list()
elif args.target == 'user':
    user_list()
else:
    all_list()
```

I know this can be done way, way better than this; but with my limited knowledge of Python, I can't seem to figure this one out.

Recap: I want something like, if at all possible (pseudocode)

```
if args.action == 'add':
    target = args.target
    target_add()
```

where `target_add()` is something like `domain_add()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would something like this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python

Comment: You may be interested in [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt), it is "argparse for humans".

Comment: @favoretti; yeah, as far as I can see this is much like the accepted answer to this question :)
@PauloScardine I understand argparse after reading a lot of the documentation and lots of questions about it on stackoverflow :), however, I got stuck with on the inner workings of python-code itself ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like action could be `list` or `add`, while `target` could be `domain`, `forwarding`, `transport`, or `user`. Yes, you would end up with a lot of `if..then..else` code if you had to manually list what each combination of options would do.

Here is a way to simplify this:

- Use itertools.product to generate all the possible combinations of
  options.
- Use a whitelist dispatch dict to map options to functions. The keys are 2-tuples, such as `('domain','list')`, or `('transport','add')`. The values are the associated function objects.

---

```
import itertools as IT

targets = 'domain forwarding transport user'.split()
actions = 'list add'.split()

dispatch = {key:globals()['%s_%s' % key] for key in IT.product(targets, actions)}

# This calls the function specified by (target, action).
# The `dict.get` method is used so that if the key is not in `dispatch`, the `all_list` function is called.
dispatch.get((args.target, args.action), all_list)()
```

Comment: Awesome, this works like a charm for me and has also cut my code in half! :)